# javascript / lodash binary search by function

Tags: javascript, lodash, binary-search

For most such operations, we're using the lodash library. I'm open to other suggestions, but would likely just write the function myself before importing a new lib.

lodash has `sortedIndexOf`, which performs a binary search in a sorted array (returns index of match or -1 if not found). It also has `sortedIndexBy`, which, using a binary search, finds the index to insert a new element where you can specify a function to use to do the sort comparison (returns a valid index if not found)

I cannot find a function to do a find (return index only if found) using an efficient sorted search allowing you to specify the sort value function. It might look something like this:

```
_.sortedFindBy(array, value, function(x){x.timestamp})
```

I believe I could use

```
var idx = _.sortedIndexBy(array, value, function(x){x.timestamp})
return (array[idx] && array[idx].timestamp === value.timestamp) ? idx : -1
```

but it just seems odd to me to not have the syntactically more compact and intuitive form of an already feature-rich set of sorted search functions.

Am I missing something from the lodash docs? Is there a built in way to do this more idiomatically? Or should I go with my extra-check method?

Comment: I don't think you're missing anything from the docs, and there isn't an idiomatic way that I could find that was more efficient than what you wrote.

Answer (score 7):

Reading through lodash code, looks like it has a pair of functions to search for a minimum index to insert an element while keeping array sorted - `sortedIndex` and `sortedIndexBy`. Former takes an array and a value, latter also accepts `iteratee` - a function, that is invoked for each element. Note, there are also `sortedLastIndex` and `sortedLastIndexBy`. Those look for the last index at which to insert a value.

When it comes to checking whether element is in the array and returning its index when it is, there's no function that accepts an iteratee, just a lonely `sortedIndexOf`. It would be only logical to have `sortedIndexOfBy` (the naming starts to get tricky here), to accept an iteratee, as well as `sortedLastIndexOfBy`.

I like your idea of naming it `sortedFindBy` and will try to implement it along with `sortedLastFindBy` and add a pull request to lodash.

Your extra-check solution is perfectly fine for now and takes advantage of the binary search optimization while not adding too much of extra code.

In the future, when `sortedFindBy` is included in lodash, you can always swap your code for the new function call.

```
_.sortedFindBy(array, value, function(x){x.timestamp})
```

You won't see any difference in performance of your code, however.

Answer (score 1):

I gave some thought on this. I don't use neither lodash nor underscore but the following pure JS code might serve your purposes. It does a binary search on sorted items of primitives or objects. A provided callback is used to retrieve the value of the object property that the array's sorting is based upon. If the callback is not provided it will default to `x => x` (`function(x) {return x}`) and it will assume the array items are primitive type. At the moment this will do only numerical comparisons but a comparison callback can also be added.

```js
Array.prototype.sortedFindIndex = function(val, cb = x => x) { // default callback for primitive arrays
  var deli = this.length-1,                                    // delta index
      base = 0;                                                // base to add the delta index
  while (deli > 0 && cb(this[base + deli]) != val) {
   deli = ~~(deli/2);
   cb(this[base + deli]) < val && (base += deli);
  }
  return cb(this[base + deli]) === val ? base + deli : -1;
};
var ara = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18],
    ina = ara.sortedFindIndex(17),
    arb = [{a:0,b:"foo"},{a:1,b:"bar"},{a:2,b:"baz"},{a:3,b:"qux"},{a:4,b:"fox"},{a:5,b:"pun"},{a:6,b:"alf"}],
    inb = arb.sortedFindIndex(4, o => o.a);
console.log(ina);
console.log(inb);
```

You can play with and modify it [here](http://www.replit.com/C2rj/1)

Answer (score 0):

The value parameter in the call to `sortedIndexBy` should have a timestamp property.

From this line:

```js
var idx = _.sortedIndexBy(array, value, function(x){x.timestamp})
```

Replace `value` by `{ timestamp: value}`

```js
var idx = _.sortedIndexBy(array, { timestamp: value} , function(x){x.timestamp})
```